# Plot3D constrained to a non-rectangular region

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I would like to make a nice 3D graphic of a parabolic bowl, with a cylindrical rim. If I do the following:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

I get a paraboloid, but the box is rectangular, so the edges come to points. I want a cylindrical bounding box. The best I've come up with is this:

```
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{x^2 + y^2, x^2 + y^2 < 1}}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

This creates a bowl, but there is also a "floor" to the graphic that I would like to get rid of. I might be able to play games with the coloring, but that seems like a poor hack. Does anyone have any suggestions?

More generally, is it possible to create a 3D bounding box of arbitrary shape?

Answer (score 9):

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 9]]
```

[image]

Re: " is it possible to create a 3D bounding box of arbitrary shape?" ... as arbitrary as your creativity for creating region functions is

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly the option I had been unable to find.

Comment: Alternatively, why not parametrize? `ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2}, {r, 0, 3}, {t, -π, π}]`

Comment: @0x4A4D Well, the title refers to `Plot3D[]` ... BTW: why the [hex conversion?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_conversion)

Comment: Well ,my message was more for the OP than you, but anyway... I got hexed, and now you're seeing the effects.

Comment: @0x4A4D [Please keep your true name concealed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rule_of_Names)

Answer (score 4):

The shorter the better :) :

```
RevolutionPlot3D[t^2, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

It is good to know `RevolutionPlot3D` in case of some axisimmetric figures but the true control is given by `RegionFuntion` introduced by belisarius.