# how to draw the intersection when a function intersected by a plane

Tags: graphics

I'm sorry, this maybe a very basic question.
$z=x^2+y^2$ that intersects a plane passing through the
point (1, −1, 2), which is perpendicular to the xy-plane and parallel to the vector $u<\frac{3}{5},-\frac{4}{5}>$.
the graph should look like

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [equation for a plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) that using a point on that plane plus the normal vector is

$$\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0)=0$$

So we need the normal vector for the plane, and we have enough information to get it.  You know your plane is perpendicular to the xy plane, which means the normal vector is parallel to the xy plane, i.e. it has no z component, so we just need the x and y components.  This is simple enough to do by hand, using the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133183/210969), but we are using *Mathematica* so let's do it that way,

```
Solve[{{3/5, -4/5}.{x, y} == 0, Norm[{x, y}] == 1}, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> -(4/5), y -> -(3/5)}, {x -> 4/5, y -> 3/5}} *)
```

Either of these will work, but we'll choose the latter

We can plot the above equation with `ContourPlot3D` and the function using `Plot3D`, and combine them using `Show`:

```
With[{r = {x, y, z},
  n = {4/5, 3/5, 0},
  r0 = {1, -1, 2}},
 Show[
  Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}],
  ContourPlot3D[n.(r - r0) == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 50}, 
   ContourStyle -> Blue]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

We need a bit of work to make it look like your plot.  First, we want to have the nice bowl-shape of a 2D parabola, so we use `RegionFunction` as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27170/9490).  Then we want to show the point and the vector `u`, so we'll use some `Graphics3D` primitives for that.

```
With[{r = {x, y, z},
  n = {4/5, 3/5, 0},
  r0 = {1, -1, 2}},
 Show[
  Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 16]],
  ContourPlot3D[n.(r - r0) == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 32}, 
   ContourStyle -> Blue],
  Graphics3D[{Darker@Magenta, PointSize[.05], Point[r0]}],
  Graphics3D[{Darker@Magenta, Arrowheads[.05], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{1/4, 0, 0}, {1/4, 0, 0} + 5 {3/5, -4/5, 0}}, .2]]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one (and not the best or neatest):

```
p1 = {1, -1, 2};
p2 = {3/5, -4/5, 0};
n[x_, y_, z_] := Normalize[Cross[p1, p2]].({x, y, z} - p1);
plane[x_, y_] := (w /. Solve[n[u, v, w] == 0, w]) /. {u -> x, v -> y}
p3d = Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, plane[x, y]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
    Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
pp = Quiet@
   Module[{sol = First@Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == plane[x, y]}, {x, y}]}, 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x, y /. sol, x^2 + y^2 /. sol}, {x, -2, 2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Red]];


g = Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[{p1, p2}], 
    Arrowheads[0.005], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, p2}]}];
Show[p3d, pp, g]
```

[image]

If you merely wish to show intersection look at [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and related functions.

Please look at what suppressed outputs are and post your own solution or if you get stuck update question or a new question if question departs from original.

Comment: I was wondering why the plane wasn't perpendicular to the xy plane, and I think it's because you have the normal vector as the cross product between p1 and p2, but p1 is just the coordinate that the plane passes through.  So the plane you solve for is perpendicular to the line from the origin to the point.  To get the right normal vector, you should replace p1 with `{0, 0, 1}` in the cross product, but I'm not sure how to get the plane with `Plot3D`

Comment: @JasonB I am sorry I misinterpreted the question. My principal aim was to illustrate a technique that could motivate OP to do exactly what you have done, i.e.that is not the plane I am interested in! At present I do not have access to computer (using phone)...if you want to correct otherwise I will leave with this explanatory comment thread or if time and health permits relook. Thank you for pointing out:-)