# Plotting an elliptic parabolid

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the elliptic paraboloid z=4(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2+3 but no matter what the range of x values and the range of  y values I give,  I can not plot a beautiful ellptic parabolid. This is what I tried

```
Plot3D[3 + 4 (x-1)^2 + (y+2)^2, {x, -11, 13}, {y, -26, 22}]
```

and this is what I get

[image]

I need to get something similar to this

[image]

I even tried to restrict the z values but it did not work.

Comment: `Plot3D[3 + 4 (x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2, {x, -11, 13}, {y, -26, 22}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 3 + 4 (x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 < 420]]`

Comment: At least closely related: [**27169**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27169/plot3d-constrained-to-a-non-rectangular-region/27174#27174)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `ParametricPlot3D` with re-parametrization and translation after, e.g.:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[v]/2, u Sin[v ], u^2} + {1, -2, 3}, {u, 0, 
  30}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-35, 35}, {0, 1000}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is

```
Plot3D[3 + 4 (x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -35, 35}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1000}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ClippingStyle -> None, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, ArcTan[2 #1, #2] &}]
```

[image]

Add the options `Axes -> False, Boxed -> False` to eliminate the tick marks and box, if desired.

**Addendum**

```
Plot3D[3 + 4 (x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -40, 40}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1000}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .55}, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, Mesh -> {15, 29}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 - 3 &, ArcTan[2 #1 - 2, #2 + 2] &}, 
    ViewPoint -> {0, 100000, 42000}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[Max[.6 #3/1000 - .4, -.18]] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

gives an image closer to that in the question.  Better agreement probably would require a nonlinear `ColorFunction`.

[image]

Comment: +1 adjusting the plot range and box ratios and nice mesh functions much more natural than my answer...I just like reparametrizations...:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I apologize that I can not upvote your answer as I do not have enough reputation to be able to upvote.

Comment: @ubpdqn  +1 I like reparameterization too and wish I had thought of it here.  Best wishes.