# Overlaying lattice graph and evaluation over lattice

Tags: graphics

I am new to Mathematica and am wondering how to plot a function over a lattice, and have it's lattice be shown beneath it (with edges).

Say we have some function $f(x,y)$ (doesn't matter what) for some values $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to plot this function over a triangular lattice, and then have the triangular lattice below it (along with the edges).

The best I've been able to do is:
[image]

```
Show[ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {White, Opacity[0.75]}, Mesh -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Black, Opacity[0.5], PointSize[0.01], Point[data]}], 
 Graphics3D[LatticePlotTwoDimensions[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, -0.2}]]
```

where `data` denotes the evaluations of $f$, and is obtained via

```
Evaluations = Map[f[#] &, Lattice];
data = Transpose[Append[Transpose[Lattice], Evaluations]]
```

and `LatticePlotTwoDimensions` denotes a ListPlot of Lattice, i.e.

```
ListPlot[Lattice, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

**Note:** I am also wanting to colour certain nodes of the lattice (beneath the plot and above it) according to their position (i.e. all points between the two peaks to be red say, and I'm not sure how to do this either. In particular, I would like to put this below it:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

---

In case it is useful, I construct the triangular lattice via:

```
FullLattice := 
  Flatten[
   Table[
    x*{1, 0} + y*{-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {x, -10, 20}, {y, 0, 7}],
    1];
Lattice := Select[FullLattice, -5 < #[[1]] < 5 &];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]

vcolor = If[0 < f[#1, #2] < 2, Red, Blue] & @@@ Lattice;
data = {#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} & @@@ Lattice;

g = IndexGraph[NearestNeighborGraph[Lattice]];
```

With ListPlot3D:

```
Show[{ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {White, Opacity[0.75]}], 
  Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[{#1, #2, -1.5} & @@@ 
      Lattice, {Line[List @@@ EdgeList[g]], PointSize[.015], 
      Point[Range[Length[Lattice]], VertexColors -> vcolor]}],
    GraphicsComplex[
     data, {PointSize[.015], 
      Point[Range[Length[Lattice]], VertexColors -> vcolor]}]}]}]
```

or custom polygons:

```
Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[
   data, {EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0.2]}], 
    Directive[Lighting -> Automatic, GrayLevel[1], 
            Opacity[0.75]], 
    Polygon[FindCycle[g, 3, All][[All, All, 1]]]}], 
  GraphicsComplex[{#1, #2, -1.5} & @@@ 
    Lattice, {Line[List @@@ EdgeList[g]], PointSize[.015], 
    Point[Range[Length[Lattice]], VertexColors -> vcolor]}],
  GraphicsComplex[
   data, {PointSize[.015], 
    Point[Range[Length[Lattice]], VertexColors -> vcolor]}]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Thank you! This did precisely what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `Plot3D` of your function surface, combine it with a `Graphics3D` of the `Point`s you want displayed, and limit the display to the triangle you want using this answer: [Plot3D constrained to a non-rectangular region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27169/plot3d-constrained-to-a-non-rectangular-region)

For example:

```
pts1 = Table[
   Point[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], 
     Sin[data[[i, 3, 1, 1]]] + Sin[data[[i, 3, 1, 2]]]}], {i, 
    Length@data}];
floorpts1 = 
  Table[Point[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], -2}], {i, Length@data}];
pl3d = Plot3D[
  Sin[x] + Sin[y], {x, Min[data[[;; , 1]]], Max[data[[;; , 1]]]}, {y, 
   Min[data[[;; , 2]]], Max[data[[;; , 2]]]},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x - y + 1]];
Show[{pl3d, Graphics3D[{pts1, floorpts1}]}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]
```